# make Styles in material ui is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm just trying to learn material ui for react especially `makeStyles`.

I've the following `javascript` code.

---

```js
import React from "react";
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
import EventNoteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/EventNote";
import ScheduleIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Schedule";
import NoteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Note";
import AttachMoneyIcon from "@material-ui/icons/AttachMoney";
import NotificationsIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Notifications";
import Brightness4Icon from "@material-ui/icons/Brightness4";
import AccountCircleIcon from "@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle";
import { Button, IconButton, makeStyles, Tooltip } from "@material-ui/core";

export default function Dashboard() {
  const useStyles = makeStyles({
    whiteIcon: {
      color: "white",
    },
    blueBtn:{
        color: "#717171",
        border: "2px solid #5B97CF",
        borderRadius: 9,
        backgroundColor: 'white'
    }
  });

  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div className="navbar">
        <div className="icons">
          <Tooltip title="Menu" placement="right">
            <IconButton classes={classes.whiteIcon}>
              <MenuIcon style={{ color: "white" }} />
            </IconButton>
          </Tooltip>
          <Tooltip title="My Appointments" placement="right">
            <IconButton>
              <EventNoteIcon style={{ color: "white" }} />
            </IconButton>
          </Tooltip>
          <Tooltip title="My Daily schdule" placement="right">
            <IconButton>
              <ScheduleIcon style={{ color: "white" }} />
            </IconButton>
          </Tooltip>
          <Tooltip title="My Projects" placement="right">
            <IconButton>
              <NoteIcon style={{ color: "white" }} />
            </IconButton>
          </Tooltip>
          <Tooltip title="Expense Manager" placement="right">
            <IconButton>
              <AttachMoneyIcon style={{ color: "white" }} />
            </IconButton>
          </Tooltip>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="dash-container">
        <div className="header">
          <Tooltip title="Notifications">
            <IconButton>
              <NotificationsIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </Tooltip>
          <Tooltip title="Toogle Light/Dark Mode">
            <IconButton>
              <Brightness4Icon />
            </IconButton>
          </Tooltip>
          <Tooltip title="Your Account">
              <Button startIcon={<AccountCircleIcon />} classes={classes.blueBtn} >Your Account</Button>
          </Tooltip>
        </div>
        <div className="dash-content">
          <div className="dash-recent-projects"></div>
          <div className="other"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

As you can see the design is very simple. I want to make a navbar and a header that holds some icons with their tool tips. I want to customize the icons by changing the colour **using `makeStyles`**. Also I want to customize the default **ugly material**  as well. I don't know where I went wrong. Pls help me

For reference, I'm also attaching the image of output.

**And one more thing**

I'm using `django` and react together. However `django` takes care of the backend only. No idea whether it has anything to do with my problem but still . . . :)

[image: Final Result :(]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is on your use of mui `classes` property where `whiteIcon` and `blueBtn` should be the key to the CSS rule names you find [here for IconButton](https://mui.com/api/icon-button/) and [here: for Button](https://mui.com/api/button/). scroll down to the **CSS** part.

so should be, for example: `classes={{root: classes.blueBtn}}`

please mark as response if you're satisfied

regards